# Moving The Applications Menu To the Dock

Tags: applications

Is there a way to move the Applications menu from the upper left corner to the dock somewhere?  So it's more Mac like?

Thanks

Comment: Four views.....wow, great support community....

Answer (score 0):

just drag it from Applications to the dock...